# Set up an existing Django app on another server

Tags: django

This must, must, *must* be a duplicate but I can't find the answer either here or on Google.

I have an existing Django app and I want to deploy it on another server.

What are the steps I need to go through to get it running elsewhere, in words of one syllable?

At a minimum, presumably:

- create a project on the new server
- copy over all my app's files into that project
- edit `localsettings.py` or equivalent with local database settings etc
- run `python manage.py syncdb` to create my database
- load fixtures
- run tests

Is that it? Are there any unofficial or official instructions for copying an app elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm aware of http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/ but it doesn't have any mention of the more mundane parts of the process: copying over files, editing local database settings, setting up database, etc. Would be useful to have a definitive reference guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic, easy way to do it is:

1. Set up the server environment so that it matches the current environment as closely as possible.  The most important thing is that you're using the same version of Django (obviously).  You can run a different database, but it makes porting from the old server to the new server a little more involved.  Otherwise, you will just have to adjust your settings to match the new server, if they can't be duplicated (ie, user names, etc).
2. Copy over your code
3. Dump your old database structure and data into the new database

Running `startproject` isn't strictly necessary.  Your web server just needs to be configured correctly, to run django with the appropriate `settings.py` file -- and Django takes it from there.

Comment: The useful thing that `startproject` does is to create a new settings.py, with its own specific SECRET_KEY value. If you copy an existing one, you'll get a duplicate key, which is bad for security.

Comment: You can always change SECRET_KEY directly in the settings file -- you don't really have to run startproject to generate a random string for you.